# F# How do a create a loop in a console app that loops through a method until a certain key is hit

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have C# console app with an infinite loop method that looks like this

```
while (true) 
{
    Event eventObj = session.NextEvent();               
    foreach (Message msg in eventObj)   
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have tried to port it to F# in this way, adding functionality that exits the loop if the "Q" key is pressed.

```
member private this.SynchronousRespsonse =
    let rec checkResponse = 
        let c = System.Console.ReadKey()
        if c.Key = System.ConsoleKey.Q then
                 this.unsubscibe
        else  
            let eventObj : Event = session.NextEvent()
            for msg in eventObj do
                printfn "%A" msg.ToString
     checkResponse
```

But it is not working.
Console output is:

```
checking...
<fun:checkResonse@41-1>
Unsubscribing ...
```

How can I write the loop to accomplish the same as the C# one while adding a convenient way to exit the loop?

**Edit:** 
I'm looking for a way to have it loop checking for new events but stop if the "Q" key is pressed. I do not want it to wait for a key before looping again. So `System.Console.ReadKey()` is probably not the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually define  functions rather than just variables - you want something like

```
member private this.SynchronousRespsonse() =
        let c = System.Console.ReadKey()
        if c.Key = System.ConsoleKey.Q then
                 this.unsubscibe
        else  
            let eventObj : Event = session.NextEvent()
            for msg in eventObj do
                printfn "%A" msg.ToString
            this.SynchronusResponse()
```

Also, the extra `rec` binding is not required and you want the recursion to occur only in the `else` block so that you can return after `Q` is pressed

Comment: Just tried this out. It is working, but it still stops and waits for each console key before looping again. I was hoping to have it loop until the key is pressed but not wait for it. My use of `Console.Readkey` does not seem to be the correct choice. I will a look for a better way

Comment: `System.Console.KeyAvailable` maybe an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to John Palmer's solution, the recursion/looping portion of function performed exactly as I wanted. To get the exact looping stopping behaviour I wanted (always loop unless "Q" key is pressed) required a little bit more massaging. Here is the final solution

```
member private this.SynchronousRespsonse =
    let eventObj : Event = session.NextEvent()
    for msg in eventObj do                    
        // to some stuff here  
    if Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey().Key = ConsoleKey.Q then
        this.unsubscibe
    else
        this.SynchronousRespsonse
```